# GitLab and OAuth to Azure AD

Tags: gitlab, entra-id, oauth

I've been tinkering with GitLab and Azure ActiveDirectory with OAuth and allowing AD users to connect to GitLab accounts.  This is set up and works just fine.  However, GitLab won't create users for AD users on the first login - they have to create a GitLab account first.

Is there a way to automatically allow AD users into GitLab without first creating an account and/or automatically creating the GitLab account for the AD user?

For reference, the relevant GitLab configuration:

```
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['azure']
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_external_providers'] = ['azure_oauth2']
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
 gitlab_rails['sync_profile_from_provider'] = ['azure_oauth2']
 gitlab_rails['sync_profile_attributes'] = ['name', 'email']
 gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
    {
      "name" => "azure_oauth2",
      "args" => {
        "client_id" => "my client id",
        "client_secret" => "my client secret",
        "tenant_id" => "my tenant id"
      }
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the providers that will be allowed to create new accounts in the field **allow_single_sign_on**. You have set **azure** on this field, but the correct name of the provider is **azure_oauth2**. Setting the correct provider name should fix your problem.